# Can't create std::vector of std::ofstream objects

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm trying to create a vector of ofstream but it doesn't work.

```
std::vector<std::ofstream> files(10);
```

The program stops working after this line.

```
auto createFiles(int n)
{
    std::vector<std::ofstream> files;
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        std::string fileName("Card" + std::to_string(i+1) + ".txt");
        files.emplace_back(fileName);
        if(!files[i]) throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file " + fileName);
    }
    return files;
}
```

I've tried this way but it doesn't work either. (the program stops working after the first execution of `files.emplace_back(fileName);`)

Edit:
Version 1, doesn't work:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

auto createFiles(int n)
{
    std::vector<std::ofstream> files;
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        std::string fileName("Card" + std::to_string(i+1) + ".txt");
        files.emplace_back(fileName); // fails here at runtime
    }
    return files;
}

int main()
{
    auto files = createFiles(10);
}
```

And version 2, doesn't work either:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

auto createFiles(int n)
{
    std::vector<std::ofstream> files(n); // fails here at runtime
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        std::string fileName("Card" + std::to_string(i+1) + ".txt");
        files[i].open(fileName);
    }
    return files;
}

int main()
{
    auto files = createFiles(10);
}
```

Edit 2: Solved, the problem appears only with GCC 8.2.0

Comment: Does the program compile but fail in runtime? Or does it fail to compile?

Comment: Compiles but fails at runtime

Comment: Can you elaborate when you say "stops working"? What actually happens?

Comment: Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 1.242 s

Comment: What result do you get if you try to run under a debugger?

Comment: Can you provide a compete compileable program that reproduces this? Just like 5 lines of code or so?

Comment: You have `std::vector<std::ofstream> files(10);` and `std::vector<std::ofstream> files;`  both. Which one is your real code using? The first creates a `vector` containing 10 `ofstream`s that are not associated with any files so if you try to write to them you will get a runtime failure.

Comment: All the code you posted here works fine for me. Can you post a minimal piece of code (just a few lines) but a complete program that causes the error on your system?

Comment: @Lassie 0xC0000005 is an access violation

Comment: Can you post a minimal piece of code (just a few lines) but a complete program that causes the error on your system? Don't post code that is roughly the same as the code you are having trouble with. Make sure the code you post goes through your compiler and causes the error.

Comment: @Galik Edited. Not very short, but I think it's simple enough.

Comment: Thanks. Both of those complete programs work fine for me. What OS and compiler are you using? And how are you compiling this?

Comment: GCC 8.2.0,
now I tried with GCC 8.1.0 and they work as I would expect, might be some compiler bug

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug then :)

Comment: btw you know you can use `std::to_string()`?

Comment: Thanks, idk why I was thinking it's not standard.